# Bootstrap 3 grid row - center align image and text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying something fairly simple in Bootstrap 3 but can't figure out how to make it work.

The goal is to get a grid row where the first element has a tiny image (50x50) and a large height (300). The rest of the elements in the row should be the same height (300px), but their width is sized to the grid/text.

Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/fL7xpw67/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1 icon vcenter"><img src='http://placehold.it/50x50' /></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 vcenter" ><p>Element1</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 vcenter" ><p>Element2</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 vcenter" ><p>Element3</p></div>
        <div class="col-md-1 vcenter" ><p>Element4</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.vcenter {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}

.icon {
    display:table;
    height: 300px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

But I can't figure out how to get the icon to the center of the grid element. Any suggestions? Most of my code is pulled from other ideas on StackOverflow but nothing has helped.

Comment: r u looking like this?? http://jsfiddle.net/fL7xpw67/2/

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai that doesn't retain widths of OP's bootstrap grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the constraints of your question involve fixed heights, this is a relatively simple problem. Simply set your columns to that fixed height:

```
.row > div {
  height: 300px;
}
```

And then to achieve your vertical centering, use `display: table` on the column and `display: table-cell` with `vertical-align: middle` on the child:

```
.vcenter {
    display: table;
}
.vcenter p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/fL7xpw67/3/

Note that I had to add a `<p>` element to the `.icon` column in your markup.

Comment: Your test window should be at least `992px` to be able to see the `col-md` without it collapsing.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would happen if I needed a min height of 300 but potentially larger based on the content?

Comment: I wouldn't use bootstrap's grid for that, but you could use similar markup and you'd probably end up using `display: table` on the row and `display: table-cell` on the column.

Comment: I'm not suggesting using an alternative grid, I was suggesting you write your own grid. You could even use a `<table>` element to achieve the effect you're looking for.